# Conditional SQL Left join

Tags: mysql, left-join

I got two table, and i would like to join them with expected result.

```
Table 1:ItemUOM
Itemcode     UOM        Rate
Item00123    Pkt454g    454
Item00123    Pkt252g    252 
Item00123    GM         1
```

```
Table 2:  vItemBalQty 
Itemcode     UOM        BalQty    Location
Item00123    PKT454g    200       2001
Item00123    PKT252g    150       2001
```

```
Expected Result:
Itemcode     UOM        BalQty   Location
Item00123    PKT454g    200      2001
Item00123    PKT252g    150      2001
Item00123    GM         0        2001
```

But my actual result with my query is not same with expected one.

```
select a.ItemCode,a.uom,coalesce(b.BalQty,0.00) from itemuom a
left join vItemBalQty b on  b.ItemCode = a.ItemCode and a.uom = b. uom
where a.itemcode = 'Item00123' and b.location ='2001'
```

```
Actual Result:
Itemcode     UOM        BalQty   Location
Item00123    PKT454g    200      2001
Item00123    PKT252g    150      2001
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the `b.location = '2001'` condition from the `WHERE` clause to the `JOIN` condition, otherwise it turns it into an `INNER JOIN` (see the paragraph about `WHERE` conditions in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/outer-join-optimization.html)) i.e.

```
select a.ItemCode,a.uom,coalesce(b.BalQty,0.00)
from itemuom a
left join vItemBalQty b on  b.ItemCode = a.ItemCode and a.uom = b. uom and b.location ='2001'
where a.itemcode = 'Item00123'
```

As @ysth put it, adding the `b.location = '2001'` condition to the `WHERE` clause means that `b.location` can not be `NULL`, which it would otherwise be for an unmatched row, thus excluding those rows from the result. By adding to the condition to the `LEFT JOIN` we return rows which have `b.location = '2001`, but still return an empty b row where that condition is not satisfied.

Comment: oh i see, thank you for teaching.but the way how to work with "inner join"??

Comment: @JJT When the query becomes an `INNER JOIN` you will no longer get rows in the output for rows in the first table which have no match in the `JOIN`ed table. So to get your desired output, you need to use a `LEFT JOIN`, which means you cannot put a condition on the `JOIN`ed table in the `WHERE` clause (other than one which checks for a `NULL` value).

Comment: another way to put it: when you say `b.location = '2001'` in the `where` clause, you are saying it *has to* be 2001, which means there has to be a b row.  If you say it in the `on` clause with a left join, you are saying only find b rows with location 2001, but if there isn't one keep the a row anyway.

Comment: @ysth that's a good way of putting it, I've edited it into the answer.